# How to set Ajax URL dynamically?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am working with Laravel 4 and I want to perform validation with Ajax. I have 2 main problems:
1. The URL at Ajax is static, which means that if I have my app online I should put the URL for online and locally doesn't works
2. my route is insur_docs/{id} how should be URL for this?

```
jQuery('form#insur_docs_update').submit(function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/insur_docs/{id}", //my url I don't know how to put it
            type: "post",
            data: jQuery('form#insur_docs_update').serialize(),
            datatype: "json",
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                jQuery('#ajax-loading').show();
                jQuery(".glyphicon-warning-sign").hide();
            }
        })
                .done(function(data)
                {
                    $('#validation-div').empty()
                    if (data.validation_failed === 1)
                    {
                        var arr = data.errors;
                        jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value)
                        {
                            if (value.length !== 0)
                            {
                                $("#validation-div").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                                document.getElementById("validation-div").innerHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>' + value + '<br/>';
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert('No response from server');
                });
        return false;
    });
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('insur_docs/{id}', 'Insur_DocController@edit');
```

controller

```
public function update($id) {
        Input::flash();
        $data = [
            "errors" => null
        ];
        $rules = array(
            "ownership_cert" => "required",
            "authoriz" => "required",
            "drive_permis" => "required",
            "sgs" => "required",
            "tpl" => "required",
            "kasko" => "required",
            "inter_permis" => "required",
        );
        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validation->passes()) {
            $car_id = DB::select('select car_id from insur_docs where id = ?', array($id));
            $data = InsurDoc::find($id);
            $data->ownership_cert = Input::get('ownership_cert');
            $data->authoriz = Input::get('authoriz');
            $data->drive_permis = Input::get('drive_permis');
            $data->sgs = Input::get('sgs');
            $data->tpl = Input::get('tpl');
            $data->kasko = Input::get('kasko');
            $data->inter_permis = Input::get('inter_permis');
            $data->save();
            return Redirect::to('car/' . $car_id[0]->car_id);
        } else {
            if (Request::ajax()) {
                $response_values = array(
                    'validation_failed' => 1,
                    'errors' => $validation->errors()->toArray()
                        );
                return Response::json($response_values);
            }             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use laravel's url generator to create the form's action attribute and use that same attribute when doing your ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use laravel's url generator helper to create your form's action:

```
<form action="{{ URL::action('Insur_DocController@edit', $id) }}" method="post">
```

You can access it in your javascript:

```
jQuery('form#insur_docs_update').submit(function()
{
    var url = $(this).attr("action");

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: jQuery('form#insur_docs_update').serialize(),
        datatype: "json",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            jQuery('#ajax-loading').show();
            jQuery(".glyphicon-warning-sign").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

You're second problem is that you're redirecting in response to the ajax call, and that does not redirect the page. You'll need to return the url and do the redirect in javascript like this.

Controller:

```
return Response::json(["redirect_to" => 'car/' . $car_id[0]->car_id]);
```

JS (just the relevant part):

```
.done(function(data)
{
    $('#validation-div').empty()
    if (data.validation_failed === 1)
    {
        // your code
    } else {
        window.location = data.redirect_to;
    }
})
```

Comment: I have this {{ Form::model($v, array('route' => array('insur_docs.update', $v->id),'method' => 'PUT','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'insur_docs_update')) }}

Comment: should I replace with yours or is the same?

Comment: No, that should generate the correct url (as far as I know laravel). You just need to update your JS to get and use that action attribute.

Comment: Yes now it shows validation but sth else is wrong because when all fields are filled it doesn't perform update just stay in that page withowt any error

Comment: Use firebug (or a similar tool for you browser) to debug the ajax call.

Comment: jus edited my question with full controller code, because I think there is e problem, pls take a look

Comment: I'm not a laravel user so I cannot help you there. Did firebug tell you the ajax is sent? Is it done to the correct url? Is the response similar to what you expect?

Comment: uppdate is performed because values in db are changed. But it doesn't perform redirect

Comment: You're redirecting the AJAX query. You'll need to return the neccessary url and do the redirection in javascript.

Comment: I didn't get it :/ pls explain it with more details :/

Comment: which url to return? the html page? and what to redirect with ajax?

Comment: well I added this  return Response::json(["redirect_to" => car/ $car_id[0]->car_id]); at controller and then just like you said in ajax and alert ("no response server");

Comment: and now redirects to this url  http://localhost:8080/insur_docs/car/%201 and shows this error NotFoundHttpException

Answer (score 0):

```
var myUrlExtension = "whatever.php"
```

and inside the ajax

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/insur_docs/" + myUrlExtension
```

Comment: but my url is like this http://localhost:8080/insur_docs/1. How should be the extension?

Comment: Then set myUrlExtension just 1.